# Jquery setting $(this) to another element while dragging it

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug, draggable, this

I am trying to set the $(this) -while dragging the- element to a new one, but I cant seem to get it to work without getting an error in my Firebug:

```
invalid assignment left-hand side
$(this) = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");

//Gives the same result. 
$(this) = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last")[0];
```

The above examples acctualy do work in my case, but I still get the error so I assume its not the right way to do it. I have also tried other ways to do it (that dont work at all):

```
//Does not work at all.
$(this)[0] = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last")[0];
//Does not work at all.
$(this)[0] = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");
//Does not work at all.
$(this).html("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");
```

Here is a bigger picture of what I am doing:

```
$(this).html("<div class='external-event'>");
$(this).data('eventObject', { title: event.title, id :event.id });
$(this).text(event.title);
$(this).addClass("temp-class-for-detection");
$(this).addClass("external-event");
$(this).appendTo( "#external-events" );
$(this) = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");
```

This may look like a terrible way to do it, but I need to move the $(this) element out of its parent div, add it to whatever div and then set $(this) back to itself. Just that now it is refrenced to another parent div.

EDIT: I want to specify that this all is trying to be done while the element itself is being dragged. Also, I get the result I want in Firefox but with an error in my Firebug. In IE the element wont stick at all.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want to do that.

Comment: `$(this)` is not an element, it is a JavaScript object that is the result of calling the `$()` function with `this` (a keyword that often represents an element) as the argument.

Comment: Neither would I if I didnt know the exact case myself. The element (when dragged) needs to be transformed into a specific type of element and cant have the parent div it originaly has when the user starts moving it. Why does it have to do this? Because the jquery based calendar (fullcalendar) I am using doesnt accept the element drop if it is within it's original parent div.

Comment: @Dutchie432, I think you mean `this` ;)

Comment: @Android, see my update. I'm not quite grasping the situation, so correct me if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

I think your a little mixed up with what $(this) is. reference to this is whatever the current scope is. $(this) for example is the jquery selector for the current scope.

instead of doing:

`$(this) = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");`

just do this:

`var _this = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");`

And now whenever you want to reference the #external-events selector simple _this.css

Comment: I still need to set $(this) to the return of the selector, and then I get the same error.

Comment: invalid assignment left-hand side
[Break On This Error] $(this) = _this.css;
I am getting more and more convinced that this is an Firebug issue, I tried all the adviced that have been posted and they either dont acctually set the $(this) element to the needed one, or give the same error. THOUGH i want to repoint, that I get the result I want, but WITH the error. Thats what frustrates me; the error.

Comment: No, I mean your *original* error. A screenshot would also work.

Comment: "invalid assignment left-hand side
$(this) = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");" - is the Firebug console error.

Comment: I don't think you can assign something to $(this) and thats why your getting that error.(really doubt its a Firebug issue, just in case restart firefox, I've ran into problems before and that seemed to fix the problems) Sorry was suppose to be _this.css({properties}); (as an example on calling jquery methods through the variable

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, I'm not sure why you have to do this (no pun intended), but if you must, why not use an alternate variable? You can use a dollar sign, if that makes you happy:

```
$this = $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last");
```

Actually, if I'm understanding you correctly, can't you just use a `.each()` statement? It's a bit hacky, but lets you use `$(this)`:

```
$(this).html("<div class='external-event'>");
$(this).data('eventObject', { title: event.title, id :event.id });
$(this).text(event.title);
$(this).addClass("temp-class-for-detection");
$(this).addClass("external-event");
$(this).appendTo( "#external-events" );

$("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last").each(function() {
  $(this).css('foo', 'bar'); // Now $(this) points to the thing above
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the try, but it aint getting me further. This is what I end up doing if I was to do it your way: var bThis = $(this);
        $("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last").each(function() {
         bThis = $(this);
        });
        $(this) = bThis; And thats the same as I have tried allready, same Firebug error. Remember its the error that is the issue, not getting the result I want or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do it `this`:

```
var that = $(this).clone();
```

.. do all your stuff to `that`

```
that.appendTo( "#external-events" );
$(this).replaceWith($("#external-events.temp-class-for-detection:last"));
```

You need to clone it because otherwise all your work will just be replaced (and in the new location you appended it to). It sounds like you want to do a bunch of stuff and then replace its *original* incarnation with that select. `This` should do `that`.

Comment: Your the closest one to understanding my problem, tought it doesnt seem like the element "sticks" to the mouse when I am dragging when I use your method. So when I do run the replaceWith method i am dragging nothing. I guess I should have specified in the questio that this is complicated with an dragging event.

Comment: I'm not totally sure I understand how all the pieces fit together so it may not be right. Clone will create a new element so yeah it would not longer be associated with some external event (I guess the mouse), not sure what else to suggest.

Comment: Wait I didn't really see this before, but your last line of code, the one in question, is basically just setting `this` to itself? Won't that selector return the same object? So my code would just replace an element with a copy of itself. Why do you need that last line at all?

Comment: Exactly, its setting itself to an changed version of itself. If I remove the last line the element it is in a wrong condition and the dropdiv doesnt accept it. Discussing this is even abstract to me, I would probably be better of trying to find a way to attach a totally new element to the mouse when I am dragging, than changing the current element.

Comment: Changing an element that is part of a DOM (such as `this` is) changes it in real time. There is no concept of replacing something with a changed version of itself, if you change it, you've already done that. If you want to make a copy of something so that the new object is no longer the same physical thing as the old one, that's what my code does, but that would break any references to anything else that's using it. Working with `this` works with the actual element in the DOM not a copy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do anything.

The `$(this).appendTo( "#external-events" );` will change the parent. `$(this)` will continue to to point to the moved element.